# Triple sorting with expression by SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

Let's imagine, I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbla (id SERIAL, curr DATE, active BOOLEAN);
```

And there are records in "tbla":

```
  INSERT INTO tbla(curr,active) 
  VALUES
        (DATE '2016-05-20', TRUE), 
        (DATE '2016-05-26', FALSE), 
        (DATE '2016-04-11', TRUE) 
        (DATE '2016-06-15', TRUE), 
        (DATE '2016-07-01', FALSE), 
        (DATE '2016-04-01', FALSE), 
        (DATE '2016-08-07', TRUE);
```

It's list of tasks, and "curr" is date of deadline. I wanna see in result list only actual tasks for current time(curr > now()), and completed tasks in the end of list, but with sorting by chronological order. "active" column means if "TRUE" then task is completed successful, else "FALSE" then task is failed completed. I don't care about "active" in actual tasks(curr > now()), but in completed tasks, I wanna see in top only  tasks which completed successful.
I wrote the following query for it(`NOW()` is `DATE '2016-06-02'`):

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM tbla 
  ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN curr < NOW() THEN 
            DATE '3000-01-01' 
        ELSE curr 
    END, 
    CASE
        WHEN active = FALSE THEN
            DATE '1970-01-01'
        ELSE curr
    END DESC,
    curr DESC;
```

And I got correct answer for me:

```
  4 | 2016-06-15 | TRUE
  5 | 2016-07-01 | FALSE
  6 | 2016-08-07 | TRUE
  1 | 2016-05-20 | TRUE
  3 | 2016-04-11 | TRUE
  2 | 2016-05-26 | FALSE
  7 | 2016-04-01 | FALSE
```

I want point out, that result is consist of three parts, the first is actual tasks sorting by "curr" in asc:

```
  4 | 2016-06-15 | TRUE
  5 | 2016-07-01 | FALSE
  6 | 2016-08-07 | TRUE
```

Then the second is consist of  successful completed tasks:

```
  1 | 2016-05-20 | TRUE
  3 | 2016-04-11 | TRUE
```

And the last part consist of failed tasks:

```
  2 | 2016-05-26 | FALSE
  7 | 2016-04-01 | FALSE
```

I am very interested to see, how you may resolve task, described by me above.
**Can you resolve it different?**

P.S. I was using PostgreSQL 9.4, but I think question is common for all RDBMS.

Comment: I can't see what it is that you're asking. You're providing a schema, sample data, a query, output of the query, explaining the output, as if it is satisfactory to you, but there's no question?!

Comment: Can you resolve it different? It's my question. I wanna see, other ways, because I think that they are.

Comment: Well you could for example create a subquery with the case statements as extra columns then order by those, but I don't see any problems with your solution, which is the most logical and readable one. Unless you are getting the wrong answer or it performs badly, I wouldn't look into changing it.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach, using NULLs for sorting instead of made up dates in the distant past or future.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbla
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN curr >= DATE '2016-06-02' THEN curr END,
    CASE WHEN active THEN curr END DESC NULLS LAST,
    curr DESC;
```